# What is FxStreamingTexture and why does it fill up my logcat?

Tags: logging

My locgat is full of such lines:

> 01-05 10:46:40.939: D/FxStreamingTexture(3948): BasicFuture_get return m_value = android.graphics.Bitmap@4074d6b8

How can I get rid of them?